# PL/pgSQL trigger to stop a river crossing another river

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, plpgsql, spatial

I have to write a trigger to stop a river crossing another river. I'm really struggling with it and any help would be appreciated. `myriver` is the table containing all the information on the rivers. So upon `insert` of a new river if it crosses an existing river, I should receive an error. Here's what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION river_check() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $river_check$
BEGIN

-- Check that gid is given
IF NEW.gid IS NULL THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'river gid cannot be null';
END IF;

NEW.the_geom = (SELECT r.the_geom FROM myriver as r
    WHERE ST_CROSSES(NEW.the_geom, r.the_geom)); 

IF NEW.the_geom THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'a river cannot cross another river';
END IF;

RETURN NEW;

END;
$river_check$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Function river_check is linked to a TRIGGER of same name:
CREATE TRIGGER river_check
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON myriver
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE river_check();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a column of the to-be-inserted/-updated row (`NEW.the_geom`) as a temporary variable. So you will either over-write that column variable (giving the new row a bogus value), or get an irrelevant result on your `IF` check (because `NEW.the_geom` had data in it anyway before the trigger was run).

Note also that Postgres, and pl/pgsql, is strictly typed, so you can't use an arbitrary value in an `IF` statement to see if it is "empty", like you would in a scripting language like PHP.

You need to either add [a `DECLARE` block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html) to give you a proper temporary variable, and check if it `IS NULL`; Or just use an `EXISTS` check directly:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT r.the_geom FROM myriver as r
    WHERE ST_CROSSES(NEW.the_geom, r.the_geom)
)
THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'a river cannot cross another river';
END IF;
```